# How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?

Tags: java, installation, exe

If I have a Java source file (*.java) or a class file (*.class), how can I convert it to a .exe file?

I also need an installer for my program.

Comment: simple hack for applets: write a C code with main and a call to function "system" like system("appletviewer java_src_file");

Comment: Will the .exe works in windows system with no JRE ?

Comment: Just to be complete (did not try it myself because we needed exe wrapper, not installer):
Installer packages can also be created using javapackager
(see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI).
To create EXE or MSI installer, additionally Inno Setup or WiX need to be downloaded and installed.

Comment: May be [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) also helps; http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Java_Launcher

Comment: As of 2021 GraalVM is an interesting way of compiling Java to native code and officially supported by Oracle.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

#### [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javapackager.htm)

> The Java Packager tool compiles, packages, and prepares Java and JavaFX applications for distribution. The javapackager command is the command-line version.
>
> – Oracle's documentation

The `javapackager` utility ships with the JDK. It can generate .exe files with the `-native exe` flag, among many other things.

#### [WinRun4J](https://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/)

> WinRun4j is a java launcher for windows. It is an alternative to javaw.exe and provides the following benefits:
>
> - Uses an INI file for specifying classpath, main class, vm args, program args.
> - Custom executable name that appears in task manager.
> - Additional JVM args for more flexible memory use.
> - Built-in icon replacer for custom icon.
> - *[more bullet points follow]*
>
> – WinRun4J's webpage

WinRun4J is an open source utility. It has *many* features.

#### [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr)

> Packages your JAR, assets and a JVM for distribution on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X, adding a native executable file to make it appear like a native app. Packr is most suitable for GUI applications.
>
> – packr README

packr is another open source tool.

#### [JSmooth](https://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

> JSmooth is a Java Executable Wrapper. It creates native Windows launchers (standard .exe) for your java applications. It makes java deployment much smoother and user-friendly, as it is able to find any installed Java VM by itself.
>
> – JSmooth's website

JSmooth is open source and has features, but it is very old. The last release was in 2007.

#### [JexePack](https://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)

> *JexePack* is a command line tool (great for automated scripting) that allows you to package your Java application (class files), optionally along with its resources (like GIF/JPG/TXT/etc), into a single *compressed* 32-bit Windows EXE, which runs using Sun's Java Runtime Environment. Both console and windowed applications are supported.
>
> – JexePack's website

JexePack is trialware. Payment is required for production use, and exe files created with this tool will display "reminders" without payment. Also, the last release was in 2013.

#### [InstallAnywhere](https://www.flexera.com/products/installation/installanywhere.html)

> InstallAnywhere makes it easy for developers to create professional installation software for any platform. With InstallAnywhere, you’ll adapt to industry changes quickly, get to market faster and deliver an engaging customer experience. And know the vulnerability of your project’s OSS components before you ship.
>
> – InstallAnywhere's website

InstallAnywhere is a commercial/enterprise package that generates installers for Java-based programs. It's probably capable of creating .exe files.

#### Executable JAR files

As an alternative to .exe files, you can create a JAR file that automatically runs when double-clicked, by [adding an entry point to the JAR manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

---

## For more information

An excellent source of information on this topic is this article, "[Convert Java to EXE – Why, When, When Not and How](https://web.archive.org/web/20181117071040/https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html)", by Dmitry Leskov

See also the companion page "[Best JAR to EXE Conversion Tools, Free and Commercial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160808182011/https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/best-jar-to-exe-conversion-tools-free-commercial.html)"

Comment: Try this: http://javaexe.free.fr/html/en/JavaExe.html

Comment: Does `javapackager` package the JVM in the outputted executable, or does it require Java to be installed wherever the application is distributed?

Answer (score 122):

## [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

> Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables. The executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or use a bundled one, and it's possible to set runtime options, like the initial/max heap size. The wrapper also provides better user experience through an application icon, a native pre-JRE splash screen, a custom process name, and a Java download page in case the appropriate JRE cannot be found.
>
> – Launch4j's website

Answer (score 40):

> **UPDATE:** GCJ is dead. It was [officially removed](https://tromey.com/blog/?p=911) from the GCC project in 2016. Even before that, it was practically abandoned for seven years, and in any case it [was never sufficiently complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040404) to serve as a viable alternative Java implementation.
>
> Go find another Java AOT compiler.

[GCJ: The GNU Compiler for Java](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119151952im_/http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) can compile Java source code into native machine code, including Windows executables.

Although not everything in Java is supported under GCJ, especially the GUI components (see
[What Java API's are supported? How complete is the support?](https://web.archive.org/web/20161020222532im_/https://gcc.gnu.org/java/faq.html#2_1) question from the [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20161020222532im_/https://gcc.gnu.org/java/faq.html)). I haven't used GCJ much, but from the limited testing I've done with console applications, it seems fine.

One downside of using GCJ to create an standalone executable is that the size of the resulting EXE can be quite large. One time I compiled a trivial console application in GCJ and the result was an executable about 1 MB. (There may be ways around this that I am not aware of. Another option would be executable compression programs.)

In terms of open-source installers, the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) is a scriptable installer. If you're curious, there are [user contributed examples](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Category:Code_Examples) on how to detect the presence of a JRE and install it automatically if the required JRE is not installed. (Just to let you know, I haven't used NSIS before.)

For more information on using NSIS for installing Java applications, please take a look at [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications#101628) for the question "[What's the best way to distribute Java applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications#101628)"

Comment: Project is actually dead, as I can see. No news on main page

Comment: The GNU Java development has pretty much moved to OpenJDK, as the non-Oracle sources could not get access to the TCK for validation.

Answer (score 28):

You could make a batch file with the following code:

```
start javaw -jar JarFile.jar
```

and convert the .bat to an .exe using any .bat to .exe converter.

Comment: A good wrapper either brings a JRE or installs it if needed and handles error situations.

Answer (score 20):

We're using [Install4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) to build installers for Windows or Unix environments.

It's easily customizable up to the point where you want to write scripts for special actions that cannot be done with standard dialogues. But even though we're setting up Windows services with it, we're only using standard components.

- installer + launcher
- Windows or Unix
- scriptable in Java
- ant task
- lots of customizable standard panels and actions
- optionally includes or downloads a JRE
- can also launch Windows services
- multiple languages

I think Launch4J is from the same company (just the launcher - no installer).

Answer (score 18):

The latest version of [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) has been enhanced to allow good offline operation as well as allowing "local installation". It is worth looking into.

However, as of 2018 Java Web Start is no longer bundled with the newest JDKs.  Oracle is pushing toward a "deploy your app locally with an enclosed JRE" model instead.

Comment: Apparently JWS has had security tightened so much, that it requires a lot more effort than previously to get running.  It might still be useful for installers, though.

Answer (score 13):

As of JDK14, [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jpackage/packaging-overview.html) replaces `javapackager` mentioned in @Jay answer. The Windows version requires Wix 3.0 and it is fairly straightforward to take a java application and build an installer which provides EXE launcher.

It can also be used with [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) to build a cut-down Java runtime image which is bundled with the installer and only contains the set of modules needed to support your application. The `jlink` step will also be run implicitly by jpackage if no runtime is specified, but I prefer to make the JRE image separately as it will only change when you update JDK or add new module dependencies to your project.

Example main for Java class:

```
package exe;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("args["+i+"]="+args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are example steps to build on Windows - obviously you'd set up your local build environment (Maven / ant / etc) to re-produce this:

```
mkdir jpackage.input\jars tmp
javac -d tmp src\exe\Main.java
pushd tmp && jar cvf ..\jpackage.input\jars\myapp.jar . && popd
```

Check it runs:

```
java -cp jpackage.input\jars\myapp.jar exe.Main X Y Z
```

Create a runtime image with jlink for the set of modules use by your application:

```
set jlink.modules=java.base
jlink --add-modules %jlink.modules% --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress=1 --output jpackage.jre
```

In case there are missing modules above, you should check the jlink JRE runtime image can run your app:

```
jpackage.jre\bin\java -cp jpackage.input\jars\myapp.jar exe.Main X Y Z
```

Use jpackage to generate installer, with app [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675323/cannot-rerun-java-jpackage-installer-if-already-installed-second-time-just-exit/62819060#62819060) based on date+hour (this saves on need to un-install every re-install) and to print out all system properties - remove the parameter "-XshowSettings:properties" after testing:

```
set appver=%date:~6,2%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2%%time:~0,2%
jpackage --win-console --input jpackage.input --runtime-image jpackage.jre --app-version %appver% --type exe --name "MyApp" --dest jpackage.dest --java-options "-XshowSettings:properties" --main-jar jars\myapp.jar --main-class exe.Main
```

Run the installer:

```
jpackage.dest\MyApp-%appver%.exe
```

Test the application:

```
"C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe" ONE 2 THREE

... Prints system properties ...

args[0]=ONE
args[1]=2
args[2]=THREE
```

Answer (score 12):

IMHO [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) seems to do a pretty good job.

Answer (score 9):

I would say launch4j is the best tool for converting a java source code(.java) to .exe file
You can even bundle a jre with it for distribution and the exe can even be iconified.
Although the size of application increases, it makes sure that the application will work perfectly even if the user does not have a jre installed. It also makes sure that you are able to provide the specific jre required for your app without the user having to install it separately.
But unfortunately, java loses its importance. Its multi platform support is totally ignored and the final app is only supported for windows. But that is not a big deal, if you are catering only to windows users.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Janel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/janel/). This last works as an application launcher or service launcher (available from 4.x).

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use some java-to-c translator (e.g., [JCGO](http://www.ivmaisoft.com/jcgo/)) and compile the generated C files to a native binary (.exe) file for the target platform.

Comment: I'm very incredulous of this method's effeciveness. I'd have to see it to believe it (think about the fact that most Java code is API calls to the JRE, and all of that isn't present on C, nevermind the differences in how the language works).

Answer (score 6):

I can be forgiven for being against converting a java program to a .exe Application and I have My reasons. the Major one being that a java program can be compiled to a jar file from A lot of IDE's. When the program is in .jar format, it can run in Multiple Platforms as opposed to .exe which would run Only in very limited Environment. I am for the Idea that Java Programs shoudl not be converted to Exe unless it is very neccesary. One can always write .bat files that runs the Java program while it is a jar file.

if it is really neccesary to convert it to exe, Jar2Exe converter silently does that and one can also attach Libraries that are compiled together with the Main Application.

Comment: The thing is, java's power is the portability, but a lot of people just need a basic windows exe.  Personally, I love java's concept... but would like to distribute something my users could run, without having to download a JRE.

Comment: That's where Java's power lies, as now with the new 'javapackager' tool, you can wrap your jar files in formats that are suitable for all of Linux, macOS and Windows systems. Yes it's good to be able to use .jar files directly, but it ain't very user friendly. Instead it is better to wrap it in all possible formats for all systems instead of limiting the user to .exe for example, and providing them on the product's website or any other way of distribution.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert jar to exe using [jar2exe](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/). However you need to purchase the software. If you need a open source software i would suggest [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

*Cautionary note:* Much has changed with packaging and deployment since this question was first asked. Most of the answers given are not even current with JIGSAW (Java 9+).

If the goal is to create OS specific packages, information is provided in Oracle Docs Java 17 [Packaging Tool User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/7/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A). This guide includes documentation for the `jpackage` tool, which allows one to create platform-specific packages for Linux, macOS and Windows. I assume the Windows-specific instructions should include arriving at an .exe file, since that remains the most familiar way for Windows users to install and run applications.

My own personal experience creating an exe (for sale on itch.io) was with the *Java Platform, Standard Edition Deployment Guide*, which included making use of the tool *Inno Setup 5*. This documentation is older, is for Java 9. The section directly pertaining to .exe packaging is located [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG600) As a first step, I used `jlink` to make a self-contained package. At the time I was first wrangling with this, I was unable to figure out how to get `jpackage` to work with my modular program. But now that Jigsaw has been around for several years, `jpackage` is now likely much easier to use, and would be my first choice for the next Java app I might publish for Windows users.

Comment: This isn't really an .exe in the sense of an executable (like a portable app). This creates an installer. The closest you can get is using `jpackage` with the `appimage` format/output. This will give you a folder with an actually .exe. But other assets are in the folder beside the .exe. Actually smooshing all the files/folders into one single .exe.. I'm not sure how that's done.

Answer (score -2):

Java projects are exported as Jar executables. When you wanna do a .exe file of a java project, what you can do is 'convert' the JAR to EXE   (i remark that i putted between quotes convert because isn't exactly this).

From intelij you gonna be able to generate only the jar

Try following the next example : https://www.genuinecoder.com/convert-java-jar-to-exe/