# Java version mismatch in Maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm having an odd problem, when attempting to build my application using Maven, *on the command line*. (Other questions I've seen on SO are referring to building within Eclipse, or some other IDE)

When I attempt to build, maven complains that it cannot find Javac in tools.jar. Looking at the given location, it is obvious that Maven is looking in the JRE directory, however, I seem unable to get Maven to point to the correct Java_home for my JDK - any ideas on how this should be done?

**Environment Overview**

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.6.0_27
Path=C:\jdk1.6.0_27\bin;...... (showing the jdk is the first thing on the path)

D:\> javac -version
javac 1.6.0_27  <-- This is correct

D:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"  <-- wtf? 

D:\>mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 03:16:01+0800)
Java version: 1.6.0_31                       <--- This is the problem - Where
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6  <--- does Maven get this from?
```

Any light you could shed on this would be most welcome.

Comment: Override the PATH variable in cmd mode with only JDK and MAVEN paths and try again. Indeed its an odd problem.

Comment: Good idea, but I still got the same response from Maven, and Java -version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Configure the toolchains.xml in your maven directory (e.g D:\maven-2.2.1\conf) to your java version

```
<toolchains>
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.5</version> <!--This should be same as is configured via the toolchains plugin -->
        <vendor>ibm</vendor> <!--This should be same as is configured via the toolchains plugin -->
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at your your build-local.properties or build.properties? possibly still pointing to theJRE there.
This has to purely be a build path issue somewhere along the path.

Sorry for listing this as an answer for i cant seem to add comments.

Comment: I don't have a build.properties, however I did check my settings.xml inside ~/.m2 and there is nothing listed in there about JRE/JDK :o(

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222560/build-failed-question-maven-jre-or-jdk-problem) does this help at all

Comment: I saw this posting during my initial research, but it relates to working in Eclipse (and just for reference, my eclipse already points to C:\jdk1.6.0_27)