# Maven builds project with Java 1.6 even if 1.5 is specified

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java version mismatch in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112721/java-version-mismatch-in-maven)

I have a project which is configured to use Java 1.5 with maven:

```
mvn help:effective-pom

...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
...
```

My machine has Java 1.6 installed, and Maven is using it:

```
mvn -v

...
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 20:16:01+0100)
Java version: 1.6.0_21
```

I have imported the project into Eclipse (using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`), and it is building it with Java 1.5, as specified in the POM.

Now if I mark an interface implementation method with `@Override`, which is disallowed in Java 1.5 but supported in Java 1.6, then Maven will build the project without errors, but Eclipse will mark the annotation as a compile-time error and refuse to build the project.

How can I either get Maven to really compile the project with Java 1.5, or get Eclipse to compile the project using the same settings as Maven?

Comment: Latest compiler plugin is 2.5.1

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/11138745/739090 help?

Comment: Try to use the m2e plugin instead of using `maven-eclipse-plugin` and see if there is a difference. http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#Maven_Integration_for_Eclipse_vs._Maven_eclipse:eclipse_plugin

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question, but I don't have enough rep to vote otherwise. The answers so far have been quite helpful, so I guess there's no great loss if it is closed now (although I haven't resolved my problem yet)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that newer versions of the JDK 1.5 ignore the `@Override` if it is in an interface implementation method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336850/256245 I guess that JDK 1.6 does the same if it is compiling using target 1.5. That´s the reason Maven does not complain about it.

To check if Maven is really compiling to Java 1.5, you should use [Animal Sniffer Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>check-java15-sun</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <signature>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java15-sun</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </signature>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Since Eclipse have its own compiler implementation, I guess you would have to remove the `@Override` annotation from interface implementation methods to make him happy. The removal will not do any harm since the annotation was being ignored by the JDK.

Comment: Strangely, adding a reference to NavigableMap does not produce compiler errors in either Maven or Eclipse. Thanks for that link, I'll see if I can update the Java 1.5 that Eclipse is using.

Comment: My bad about NavigableMap. The correct way to verify Java 1.5 compatibility is using Animal Sniffer Plugin. I edited the answer to reflect this.