# Maven unable to locate Javac Compiler - Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:

Tags: java, maven, m2e

When I try to make maven-install on my gwt-maven Projekt i get this Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project MyProject: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
[ERROR] C:\Development\java jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
[ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
[ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
[ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
[ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

But `JAVA_HOME` is set. When I run `cmd "echo %JAVA_HOME%"` it says `C:\Development\jdk7` and this is correct.
Dont know why he is searching for `C:\Development\java jre7`.....

Comment: Have you made settings in mavenrc.bat ? Have you restarted the cmd exe after changing the JAVA_HOME on Windows ?

Comment: no. i havent made settings in mavenrc.bat. and no i havent restartet because JAVA_HOME is set since... i dont know ... long time ago ^^

Comment: Maybe try using a newer version of the maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: There is a higher version than 2.3.2? Because my Eclipse cant find one ^^

Comment: Could you post your `pom.xml`? Are you running from inside eclipse or command line?

Comment: Can you also mention whether you are executing this from eclipse m2e?

Comment: Im running from inside eclipse.

May pom.xml is much to big for a commend Post :)

Comment: Yes i use the m2e plugin.

Comment: m2e has problems with pathnames with whitespace, I believe.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. i deleted the whitespace from my java path and everything is all right now

Comment: Retagged with m2e. It would have been easier and good practice if you update your question with dev environment information. Cheers :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like your JAVA_HOME might be pointing to a JRE instead if a JDK?

```
C:\Development\java jre7\..\lib\tools.jar
```

Do you have a JDK installed? If so, change your JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK instead.
If not, download the JDK first and then set JAVA_HOME.

**Update**

Since you're running from inside Eclipse your answer is on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222560/build-failed-question-maven-jre-or-jdk-problem)  - you need to tell Eclipse to use the JDK and not the JRE.

Comment: @user1882812 I think he's correct.  Can you compile anything on your machine with `javac`?

Answer (score 4):

For eclipse user:
**Way 1:**

1. Right Click on Eclipse project -> Go to Properties
2. Java Build Path -> Libraries
3. Click on JRE System Library -> Click Edit button at right side -> Click on Installed JRE
4. Edit JRE -> Set JRE Home = JAVA_HOME (In my case JAVA_HOME is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45)

**Way 2:**

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Edit the existing JRE location as: Set JRE Home = JAVA_HOME or JAVA_HOME\jre (In my case the path was C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 OR C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre)
3. Click Finish and OK button

**Way 3:**

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs
2. Select the JRE you are using
3. Press Edit -> Add External JARs...
4. Browse to Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib and select tools.jar and Press Enter
5. Click Finish and OK button

Comment: Good to hear PSR 7

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Development\java jre7" has to be *somewhere*. Double-check your environment and your scripts. It can't be invented out of thing air. Maven will respect JAVA_HOME, so, something, somewhere, is using that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you also need to add in window > preferences > java > Installed JRE's ,
point to the JDK version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, actions like importing Maven projects or invoking "Update Sources" runs in the same JVM in which Eclipse is running. If that JVM comes from JRE that isn’t part of JDK, there would be no Java compiler (the tools.jar).

So to launch Maven from within Eclipse, JRE used for launch also need to come from JDK. By default Eclipse registers JRE  from which it started, but this can be configured as follows:

Go to "Window / Preferences… / Java / Installed JREs" preference page

Click on JRE > Edit

Set JRE Home with same value as that of your JAVA_HOME env variable

Answer (score 0):

If this error comes in `Jenkins`, then you need to set the path of JAVA_HOME in Jenkins.

1. Go to Manage Jenkins
2. Global Configuration Tool -> JDK
3. set the path of JAVA_HOME: