# Error during Maven execution

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run the maven and returns me the error:

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn: 227: exec: /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java: not found
```

What can it be?

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the JDK?

Comment: Make sure that JDK is in the PATH and JAVA HOME env variable and refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222560/maven-build-failed-unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler-in-jre-or-jdk-issue)

Comment: Is your java under /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin ?

Answer (score 0):

run the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` and see where the java home is set and verify if the path is correct. Then check if `$JAVA_HOME\bin\`  folder is there and check for `java` command in it.

Answer (score 0):

I just was experiencing this same problem, and about 4 hours later I figured it out. I had installed the wrong version of the java JDK. I originally installed the Linux x-86 version, but my computer settings required the x-64 version. Make sure you have the version of the Java JDK that is compatible with your system. Here's the link to those JDK downloads: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html