# mvn clean warning and mvn install error

Tags: java, maven

Hi Guys I have these two issues

```
mvn clean
```

I get this warning msg

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.souq.marketplace:selling-center-services:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.souq:servicemanager:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/servicemanager-1.1.1.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 138, column 16
>   [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin @ line 453, column 12

second is when i do install

```
mvn install
```

> Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: [ERROR]
>   /opt/jre1.7.0_71/../lib/tools.jar [ERROR] Please ensure you are using
>   JDK 1.4 or above and [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main
>   class is required). [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location
>   of your Java [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment
>   variable. [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

> /opt/jre1.7.0_71

Comment: You have to install JDK and set JAVA_HOME environment variable path to your JDK

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven build failed: Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: jre or jdk issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222560/maven-build-failed-unable-to-locate-the-javac-compiler-in-jre-or-jdk-issue)

Comment: @IgorPatsyan true that took care of the error :) .. but  What about the warning of mvn clean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the JRE installed but you need the JDK (eg. OpenJDK for Linux). The JRE does not contain the compiler.

Comment: what about the warning of mvn clean ?

Comment: if you could add the content of your pom.xml to your post I might be able to help you :P

Answer (score 0):

check with your JAVA_HOME variable path.
and could you please tell us your JAVA_HOME variable and your jre installation path.