# Where to get Java Standard Libraries if Eclipse don't have them?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the Android SDK witch include eclipse. Its working for developing android apps, but now I want to make a tool app for pc and I need some of the java standard libraries that where not included with the Android sdk, for example `javax.imageio.imageio`.

Where can I get these libraries ?

**I know there is a src.zip file with all the source code from java standard libraries in the Java directory**, but Is there not a jar file or something like that so i can just include it as an external library ?

Comment: [Download the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), and [install it in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/998643/571407).

Comment: That did not work...

Comment: Ah, the famous "did not work" problem. This is easily fix by applying the solution "then try again".

Comment: Ok, thanks. But It still don't work, I think I better make a library out of the java source code from src.zip

Comment: My above comment was a way to make you realize that "it doesn't work" doesn't mean anything. We can't help you with such a vague description of the problem. We don't have any idea of what you actually did, and of what the problem is. Likewise, if you told us **what** it says, instead of saying "it still says the same thing", we could perhaps help.

Comment: Sorry, It says "ImageIO cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Have you configured your project to use the newly installed JDK? Have you imported javax.imageio.ImageIO in your class?

Comment: Now I have a new error on the import javax.imageio.imageio that says "Access restriction: The type ImageIO is not accessible due to restriction on required library B:\Java\lib\rt.jar"

Comment: It seems you have created an Android project. Not a regular Java project.

Comment: I am sure I have created a Java project

Comment: I think the problem is that I use the android eclipse that leak some libraries, but I can still make Java projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me !

1. Go to the Build Path settings in the project properties.
2. Remove the JRE System Library
3. Add it back; Select "Add Library" and select the JRE System Library.

Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar).

Answer (score -1):

You should [edit your build.gradle](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N105A1) file.  There is a dependency section in there.