# Have a Java application (JAR) that needs to be executable. (Built In Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this little application (JAR) built in Java on Eclipse and it needs to be compiled into an executable file that people can just double-click and it runs. Ideally this would an exe filetype. I'm not so versed with java and what the needs are but I'm hoping it can be compiled to run one computers that maybe don't have java installed.

Is there any advice or direction you can point me to so I can figure this out?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally this would an exe filetype.

No, ideally this would be a Jar file. Just leave it be a jar file. It will work fine if you set up your platform to respond to double clicks correctly. And yes the computer will need to have Java installed -- that's not an onerous requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this application : exe4j : http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html

It runs on various platforms to made EXE files :))

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to make it run on PCs without Java installed.

There are plenty of guides on how to make an executable jar to run on computers with Java installed: take your pick: [java executable jar creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6148111/857132),  [Make JAR as a standalone executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5066291/857132) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html.  It is free for non-commercial use.