# How to release a java application?

Tags: java, deployment, desktop-application, deploying

I just finished making a simple java desktop application.

I want to know how do I combine this app into a single executable file, so that double clicking it will run the application. Right now, I run the application through the IDE, but that's not how I want it to run forever.

Comment: create a batch file/shell script that will call `java` and pass your `.jar`/`.class` to it.

Comment: You can have a look over here for your answer: [StackOverFlow : answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program

Comment: Just google, "How to make an executable jar file".

Comment: Another way is use something like [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: One question that a lot of beginning programmers have is: "Now that I've created my application in the IDE, how do I get it to work from the command line outside of the IDE." Similarly, someone might ask, "How do I distribute this application to other users without having to give them the whole IDE as well?"

The answers to these questions are relatively simple, but not necessarily obvious.

from: https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have been using Eclipse IDE.

In your package explorer (usually on the left side), find your Java Project you wish to export, right click in it and choose `Export` from the menu.

When asked for type, expand the `Java` folder icon and choose `Runnable JAR file`.

Under `Launch configuration`, find and select your class that will run it (the one with `main` method).
Choose where you want to export it and what you want to do with the other, non-standard libraries you are using.

Click on `Finish`.