# How to make a .exe or executable jar that can be run directly?

Tags: java, jar, exe, executable-jar, runnable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create executable Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program)

I had implemented some speech recognition application in java.its working well with the eclipse when i run from eclipse..but my code not running when i m trying to run from command line ..

i had included some jar from the sphinx ..like sphinx.jar,jsapi.jar,wsj_dictionary.jar,my directory structure is as follows :

[image: my directory structure]

So can anyone suggest me how to make .exe or a executable jar file that can be run directly?

thanks in advance..

Comment: This problem is really not fixed by 'making an exe'.  I highly recommend removing all reference to the Windows specific native.

Comment: @Chris  That is not really a duplicate, once we sort out the "don't need an EXE" matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse, you can export your project into an executable JAR file by right-clicking on your source folder, selecting "Export...", selecting "Java->Executable JAR File".  Eclipse will then offer the option to either extract your external JAR dependencies into the final jar file, or place them into a folder with the final jar's manifest classpath referencing them.

Comment: *"either extract your external JAR dependencies into the final jar file, or place them into a folder with the final jar's manifest classpath referencing them."*  The latter is much more versatile.  It allows easy reuse of common APIs, amongst other benefits.

Comment: i have done that way..but then when i run that jar file from command line its hows me errro like u cant access .jar file which i have created

Comment: Thanx a lot I have succeeded..Its amazing .just a few minutes and you guyz Solved My problem..thanks a ton for that

Answer (score 3):

The `MANIFEST.MF` file in your jar should specify the Main-Class and the classpath. Something like this:

```
Main-Class: full.package.path.to.your.main.class
Class-Path: space separated list of jar files
```

You would probably want to use an automatic build tool like Ant, Maven or Gradle in order to generate the `MANIFEST.MF` file in your jar that way.

Comment: Thnaks for your help..but i ahd done with that from export and executable jar file...thnx for help

Answer (score 2):

Use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) for wrapping jars in Windows executables.