# Jar file is not running in right click context menu

Tags: java

i have a jar application and it is running fine but when i added it to the right click context menu in windows 8. it says an error that this app can not run on your pc. what to do with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `Main-Class` attribute in the `manifest.mf` file, inside the META-INF folder inside the jar. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804885/201359) for details.

Comment: i have done all this but its not working.

Comment: Try running it from the command line using `java -jar`, to check if everything's working

Comment: everything is working from the command line and even the application is running on double click. but it is not working from the right click menu of windows 8. and i am not using any frame work i am doing all this in notepad++.