# Unable to load jar manifest when opening from windows server

Tags: javafx-2, executable-jar

When running my jar file on the computer I get this weird error:
"Unable to load jar manifest"

The strange part is when I put the file on my local drive it works,
When i load it from the windows server (My home dir) it gives this error
And when i load it from a linux server our development, it works!

Finally if i run java.exe -jar "jarfile" from  the windows server it works aswell!

Anyone got any clues?

Comment: Been looking further into it and it seems like DNS issue's

When i open it from my desktop (which is dynamically linked to my homedir) it opens from \\server\path and gives the error

When i map the network drive to a letter like P:\path
it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running into the same issue now. Seems like the workaround is to make a standalone executable.

[How do I create executable Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program)

Haven't found a fix for the root problem though, for me its the new fx launcher that is throwing the error.

Comment: Yes this will work and is how we solved it. In the end it is a core java bug which can't handle UNC paths

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way with a batch file:

```
pushd pathToJarAndJava
.\javaDir\java -jar .\jarDir\yourCode.jar
popd
```