# Wrap the application to create sh file in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, shell, jar

I have created one java application which takes number of external jar files and also VM arguments passed to it.

I want to create .sh file for that application so that I cat run it on any linux system.

Please suggest me any tool to create .sh file in linux and which will also takes care about the arguments which has to be pass to application to run it.

I have use the tool named JarSplice but its not working as there is problem in loading libraries after creation of sh file .

So please suggest any tool for that.

Comment: Belongs to - [ubuntu.se]

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  Can you distribute it from the net or a network?

Comment: @RohitJain does not belong to Ask Ubuntu.  It is a programmer issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using maven to build your application there is a plugin called `appassembler-maven-plugin` that can create a `.sh` file for your application.

The groupId is `org.codehaus.mojo`.

Comment: Thnks for your suggesion.But I have created the application using eclipse in ubuntu.So what can I do now to create .sh file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate an executable jar, then you can simply run "java -jar main.jar" from there.

There are many questions on stackoverflow on how to create executable jars (you need ot set stuff in the MANIFEST.MF file in the jar file), for instance:

[How do I create executable Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program)