# How to run my a Java program as an executable .jar file?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I was wondering how can I turn my program (which I am currently running from Eclipse) into an executable file?

This will make it more feasible as people with JRE can just access it by clicking on a single file.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create executable Java program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program)

Comment: set the environment settings of the os, and add a manifest file to your jar, pointing to the class which contains the main method

Comment: Check out this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: Use http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile your java code
2. Create a `manifest.txt` file.
3. Specifiy the main class in the manifest file like: `Main-Class: com.example.Main`
4. Create a jar by adding the `manifest.txt` and required `.class` files: `jar cvfm myJar.jar manifest.txt *.class`

> Note: make sure to add **.class** files, not **.java** files.

Comment: don't forget the step "add Java to your environment settings"

Comment: Actually, @Stultuske, that is not strictly necessary.  You can always use the full pathname of the `java` command, and the CLASSPATH variable is ignored when you launch an executable JAR using `-jar`.

Comment: @StephenC which is assuming it will only run on your machine, but if it's a jar that is to be distributed, and you have no idea where Java is installed ...

Comment: But the person who installed it knows where it was installed.  But either way, it is the person who installs Java who would be setting the PATH variable ... not the person who is creating the JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

You may create this as a maven project and then simply run `mvn clean package` and the jar will be created in target directory.