# How to create a Windows executable?

Tags: java

Honestly, I have learnt Java and I can make Java Desktop application or website using Java. But the problem is that they are projects that as far as I know can only be run with IDE or using `java -jar`.

I tried searching google about "how to create a windows software" but I haven't have what I want. What I want is making a software with an executable setup file which generate everything else (Sorry, I don't know about that part too).

Comment: Java 9. Introduced a modules system. And the command `jlink`. Which you can use to create custom runtime images of your application. Try that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create executable Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804466/how-do-i-create-executable-java-program)

Comment: If you want an exe, Java 14: jpackage.exe. There also projects that build a GUI around jpackage, just google it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just want to make a program with GUI. If you just want to have GUI， you can use "JavaFx" which is one UI lib for java.

Comment: The OP says they already know how to make desktop apps, they just don't know how to run them without `java -jar`. The choice of GUI library won't help the OP run their program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a standalone executable (.exe or .jar) file from your project.

You can take help of following thread to get your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/147233/5732845

I hope I could give the relevant answer. Let me know if you want anything else.