# How can I get a free easy multiplatform installer for a java program

Tags: java, installation

Hi I made a java swing application. Also created jar of that file.
Now I want to make that file in installable format (means in .exe format for windows bin format for linux X86 format).

If we install any software we get some license agreement. I want to make my jar in that format which can be installed in any platform. So is there any free and easy to use installer which can give me that feature.
Or is there any way that I can get the same installable format using java program

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: Lots of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=launch4j

Comment: One of the duplicates, that seems to have everything you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use DiskUtility or Package Maker for Mac, Visual-Studio for Windows and RPM for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators/izpack

Comment: I have installed izpack. But unable to get installer from my jar file. My installer have also license agreement

Comment: Hi If I use izpack whether I will be able to crate license agreement for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use InstallJammer. InstallJammer cannot create installer for MacOS.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo