# InstallShield vs Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, deployment

When I deploy my application in VS2010, I see two options: **InstallShield LE** and **Visual Studio Installer**. Why are there two options? What is the advantage of using **InstallShield LE** over **Visual Studio Installer**?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just default tools that can help you create simple installers for your applications. Most difference are UI related, there's not much functionality in either of them.

If you want to choose a setup authoring tool, take a look at these threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621478/what-is-the-best-windows-installer
- [How to create an installer using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629013/how-to-create-an-installer)
- [What is the best installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734057/what-is-the-best-installer)

There are lots of threads like this which mention free and commercial setup authoring tools.

Basically, if you want a simple installer, you can use Visual Studio setup or InstallShield LE. If you want more advanced features, you need to find a different setup authoring tool that fits your needs.

Answer (score 6):

To update this a little, Microsoft seems to have thrown in the towel on their own installer project type.  It is not included in the Visual Studio 11 developer preview, and there are forum/blog posts that indicate this is no longer a supported product.  If you are searching for what to use for new projects, I would steer clear of the Visual Studio Installer.  Hopefully when VS11 finally is released, there will be a free version of InstallShield included.

Comment: Just to expand on this with new knowledge, WiX seems to be the way to go.  Most blog post from MS people don't come right out and say that, probably due to agreements with InstallShield, but they seem to be urging us toward WiX.  http://wix.sourceforge.net/