# Best Desktop Deployment technique for small Java applications

Tags: swing, setup-deployment, java

I am planning to develop a GUI Frontend for mixminion in java using swing(it would be something very simple nothing big). After making it what would be the best way to deploy it on windows for average users who dont even know whats java(leave alone JRE).So asking them to separately download JRE is not an option. I also want to keep the download size to minimum coz it will downloaded through internet so i cannot bundle JRE with installer. 
   Using Jet to compile it into a native code is not an option bcoz its not free.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+installer

Comment: [What's the best way to distribute Java applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications)

Comment: The best deployment option for a Java Swing app. is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) with the `deployJava.js` to ensure the user has a suitable minimum JRE.  JWS also works on Mac. & * nix.  As to - *"I also want to keep the download size to minimum coz it will downloaded through internet"*  Most people have cable broadband nowadays.  Even on this machine that is using a wireless connection, I can download 7+meg in around 90 seconds.  A couple of minutes, and most Win users who have no Java will be able to have it installed using the `deployJava.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your really need to create a native app, the *GNU Compiler for the Java* can produce native machine code. I have no experience using GCJ and the latest news on the website is from late 2009. So this advice comes without warranty or guarantees... However if want to try:

http://gcc.gnu.org/java/