# How to use jai image io tools in my project?

Tags: java, javax.imageio, lossless-compression

I'm trying to read some jpeg-lossless images and show in my project. by the way, these images are DICOM file. After recognizing type of image, I wrote this code:

```
if (tsuid.equals(TransferSyntax.JPEGLossless)) 
      readerWanted = "jpeg-lossless";
reader = (ImageReader) (ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName(readerWanted).next());
```

but when I ran it, I got this error:

> No reader for jpeg-lossless available for Transfer Syntax 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70
>   Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException

I've searched in the Internet and I figure out that I have to install **Image I/O Tools**. then I install that in OS and my project worked very well.

***But my problem:***
I wanna add "jai-image-io" tools in my libraries such as another jar libraries that added there,too. because my application should install on lots of client systems that I can't install extra tools. I don't know how I can do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have a same problem. unfortunately, I can found a suitable solution that solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your problem is deployment.

- You need to have the Java classes in the classpath
- You need to have the binaries in the java.library.path

Depending how you are deploying, you could use the web start versions of JAI (http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/webstart/release/) or just build your own package and put the necessary jars and libraries in a known location (then use -Djava.library.path=*<some location>* to set it).

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean? please more explain. how come?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/80597/1901261 has a good list of options for deployment.

Comment: thanks, I read it. but I don't think so WebStart can solve my problem. what about **-Djava.library.path=<some location>**? could you explain more your second suggestion?