# How to run java desktop application as other windows application?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, desktop

I need to make Java desktop application works simply while double clicking the icon. It works by double clicking the .jar file. But I need it as a different icon. And also want to see just as other windows application and need to make these application works on another computer by installing my application on it.
I used netbeans 6.0 for creating the desktop application.  How this is possible?

Comment: refer this answer, you might get something

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the .jar into a .exe, with [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).