# Pin a Java program created with Netbeans on taskbar?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, taskbar

Good evening!

I want to create a program in NetBeans which I can pin to my taskbar without detours. I just want to pull the program in my taskbar, but if I just build the project it isn't possible. Can someone tell me, what I have to add to my code or what do I have to click in NetBeans to be able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to distribute Java applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your code without using IDE, you can use the command prompt to do this, or you can make an .exe file of your code, so you can run it as a windows application (with the double-click).
Here is the name of some programs that convert java file to .exe file:

JSmooth - JarToExe - Executor - Advanced Installer - Launch4j - Install4j
Hope this help.

Comment: I didn't think about an .exe file, but it's a nice idea. I'll look at this, thanks!

Comment: Here's a step by step tutorial on how to do it with Advanced Installer, there's also a video at the end: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html

Answer (score 0):

You can even build the project as a standalone .jar file, and then simply create a shortcut to the file and pin it to your taskbar that way.

I haven't used NetBeans in ages, but in eclipse it's under the export menu.

Comment: I know that I can build is a a jar file, but I can't pin it to the taskbar then.

Comment: make a shortcut to the jar file and pin the shortcut to your taskbar.