# Deploying a Netbeans Java project hopefully as .exe

Tags: java, swing, maven, netbeans

so I think I finished my project but I still have to "deploy" it.
I was looking over at tutorials and a few of them had similar steps of going to my project properties and going to the build tab and including libraries and .JAR file and stuff but my project properties doesnt have any of the options shown in the tutorials I read. (I assume because I imported my libraries using maven, also this is a swing java GUI app I made).
I tried going to my project folder /target and found a 18 kb .JAR file (feels fairly small to me). I double click on it and nothing happens. I tried adding a bat file with "java -jar filename.jar" but nothing happens either (CMD prompt opens for a second then exits).
Hopefully I can export this as an .exe but I'm okay with a runnable .JAR file as long as it runs in any windows machine with JRE.

Comment: There are a lot of SO questions on this subject. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80105/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-java-applications).

Comment: _I tried adding a bat file with "java -jar filename.jar" but nothing happens either (CMD prompt opens for a second then exits)_ - That's not nothing. If you double-clicked on the bat file, then you may not have had time to see what happened. If that is the case, try running the bat file from the command line (i.e. open a CMD shell, cd to the relevant directory and then type the bat file name to run it).